# Conditional distribution

Tags: parameter-estimation, kalman-filter

I am trying to figure out the derivation of Kalman filter based on Bayesian estimator. As we know, the assumption of Gauss-Markov model is used, then, the conditional distribution p(x(t)|Y(t-1))can be expressed in terms of the Gaussian distribution as

$C(y(t)|x(t))\sim  \mathcal{N}(C(t)x(t),R_{vv}(t))$

$P(x(t)|Y(t-1))\sim  \mathcal{N}(\tilde{x}(t|t-1),\tilde{P}(t|t-1))$

$P(y(t)|Y(t-1))\sim  \mathcal{N}(\tilde{y}(t|t-1),\tilde{R_{ee}}(t))$

I am totally lost. Thank you in advance! By the way, this material orginates from the book "Modal Based Signal Processing (James V. Candy)" in Chapter 5 Page 296.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Note that right now, you did not ask a question.